# DataGridView bound to BindingList shows too many columns

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I've got a class with two public properties, Name and Text.  I want to bind a DataGridView to a list of these objects, so I loaded them into a BindingList<>.  I only want to show the Name property in the DataGridView, but I'm getting both columns.  What am I doing wrong?

```
private void fileOpenTextBox1_FileSelected(object sender, string e)
{
    m_definitions = new BindingList<TagSimDefinition>(TagSimDefinition.Read(e));

    dgvTagNames.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvTagNames.Columns.Clear();
    DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colTagName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = cell,
        Name = "colTagName",
        HeaderText = "Tag Name",
        DataPropertyName = "Name"
    };

    dgvTagNames.Columns.Add(colTagName);
    dgvTagNames.DataSource = m_definitions;
}
```

Comment: The code you are showing does not produce two columns.

Comment: The code I showed produces two columns for me, although I agree with you that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert you are setting,

```
dgvTagNames.DataSource = m_definitions;
```

for that it is showing both columns. If you want to get one column use it like this,

```
m_definitions = new BindingList<TagSimDefinition>(TagSimDefinition.Read(e));

dgvTagNames.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgvTagNames.Columns.Clear();
dgvTagNames.ColumnCount = 1;
dgvTagNames.Columns[0].Name = "colTagName";
dgvTagNames.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "colTagName";
dgvTagNames.DataSource = m_definitions;
```

Another solution:

```
 m_definitions = new BindingList<TagSimDefinition>(TagSimDefinition.Read(e));
 dgvTagNames.Columns.Clear();
 DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colTagName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
 {
    CellTemplate = cell,
    Name = "colTagName",
    HeaderText = "Tag Name",
    DataPropertyName = "Name"
 };

dgvTagNames.Columns.Add(colTagName);

dgvRegion.Rows.Clear();
int index = 0;
foreach (var dparam in m_definitions)
{
    dgvTagNames.Rows.Add();
    dgvTagNames["colTagName", index].Value = dparam.<Property1>;                                           
    dgvTagNames.Rows[index].Tag = dparam;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me as though your second solution is not using data binding.  It merely creates a data grid view with one column, and then walks through my list and adds the data to the grid one item at a time.  I do not see any connection from the grid back to the list.  If I change a tag name in the grid, I don't think the change will be reflected in the list.

Comment: Your first solution is just what I was looking for.  Thanks very much!  One little thing:  the data property name should be set to "Name", not "colTagName".

Comment: ohh @ROBERTRICHARDSON feeling well that it worked out and yes  property name I was confused not tested it :P so just gave a string...that's all. 2nd solution should work out but it is not using binding rather looping which is time consuming and will take time for large amount of data, that I think. Thanks so much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here is making things wayyyyyyy to complicated.  If you have columns you don't want displayed you could just set the Column.Visible = false after the setting the datasource.

```
dgvTagNames.Columns[index].Visible = false;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to know the index of the column I want  to hide.  I may not necessarily know this until I run the program.  If I add another public property to TagSimDefinition, which I am very likely to do, I will need to remember to come back here and hide the new column.  I want to ensure that I only see the one column I'm interested in, regardless of how many other public properties I may create.